# Error calling WSO2 API Manager Admin Servces via soapUI

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am experiencing an error calling WSO2 API Manager v2.1.0 Admin Services via soapUI.  It seems that the requests that are changing state in API Manager like this one, addRole, are failing.  Note that "read only" style requests like listAllUsers or getAllRolesNames are succeeding.

Here is the raw request from soapUI:

```
POST https://localhost:9443/services/UserAdmin.UserAdminHttpsSoap11Endpoint HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
SOAPAction: "urn:addRole"
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
Content-Type: application/soap+xml
Content-Length: 283
Host: localhost:9443
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xsd:addRole>
         <xsd:roleName>test_role</xsd:roleName>
      </xsd:addRole>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the response form soapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <wsa:Action>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</wsa:Action>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <soapenv:Code>
            <soapenv:Value>soapenv:VersionMismatch</soapenv:Value>
         </soapenv:Code>
         <soapenv:Reason>
            <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI</soapenv:Text>
         </soapenv:Reason>
         <soapenv:Detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the log entry that appears in wso2carbon.log:

```
[2017-03-03 16:23:03,474] ERROR - ResponseTimeCalculator wso2statistics.request.received.time is null in the IN MessageContext
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your request is a SOAP 1.1.

In that case, the `Content-Type` of the request should be `text/xml`, not `application/soap+xml`.

If that doesn't work, try using `RemoteUserStoreManagerService` instead of `UserAdmin`.